# The hadith about placing hands on chest in musnad ahmed

Tags: hadith, salat, fiqh

Following is the hadith in musnad ahmed:

> Sayyiduna Hulb (ra) relates, 'I saw the Prophet (sallallahu alaihi wa sallam) turn from both his right and left and I also saw him place this upon his chest.' Yahya (one of the narrators) described this as being the right hand upon the left above the wrist joint. (Ahmad 21460.)

Imam Nimawi comments in his al T'aleeq al Hasan (1/145):

> 'I have a    suspicion that the wording of this hadeeth has mistakenly been    changed by a writer. The correct words would appear to be "Yadhau    hadhihi ala hadhihi", i.e., "he would place this hand upon this    hand", and not "hadhihi ala sadrihi", i.e., "this hand upon his    chest". Only this wording would be in agreement with the narrators    own interpretation of the hadeeth as is stated in the narration    "Yahya described this as being the right hand upon the left above the  wrist joint". This would also tally with all the other narrations of   this hadeeth that do not contain the wording "upon the chest".

I know that this is a matter of dispute but I only wanted to know whether imam nimawi's point is valid. Because the hadith wording is quite strange as it mentions only one hand i.e. "place this hand on chest". I just want answer to this for knowledge I know this matter is broad in scope.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Imam Nimawi adds in his al T'aleeq al Hasan (1/145)

Comment: And he is imam nimawi hanafi not imam nawawi. And if you can answer precisely please. It would be beneficial.

Comment: Then it should be a an-Nymawi النيموي.

Comment: @Medi1Shah yes. And I also wanted to add that version of this musnad ahmed hadith is also present in tehqiq ibn al-jawzi with wording "یضع ھذہ علی ھذہ علی صدر" but hanafis argue that this is not found in the original manuscript. Anyways if you can shed some light on this issue.

Comment: When you check only the versions narrated on the authorithy of Hulb via his son you may find at least 20 to 40 quotes in different books at least 5-10 are in Musnad Ahmad and a similar amount in al-Bayhaqi's as-Sunan al-Kubra and twice of that in the books of at-Tabarani. This is not a topic done within an hour or two. First of all can we agree that the hadith you refer to is #326 in the book of an-Nymawi?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I know that. I only wanted to discuss about the wording "یضع ھذہ علی صدر" place this on his chest. Do you agree that this wording is odd or something?

Comment: It is an explanation, it's certainly not part of the original report. What I understand from an-Nymawi's explanation is that he made some criticism on what is called the strongest version of the majority view. But I have not yet gone through the analysis, interestingly he somewhat accuses authorities such as ibn Hajar and an-Nawawi for their misuse of hadith-science terminology.